# how to use no-cors mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, cors, http-headers, httprequest

i am trying to send data to another api that has no cors setting

in JS I can make it work by setting the no-cors mode

but I can't find anything explaining how to set mode:no-cors in flutter

I tried

```
 var r = await post(
converterUrl('https://myurl.com'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
      },
      body: corpo
  );
```

but it didn't work

I use http package

sample in JS

```
let data = {"LastName": "Teste 2",  "email": "teste2@teste.com",    "LeadSource": "Google", "MobilePhone": "",  "idEmpreendimentoInteresse__c": "", "Campanha__c": "", "UTMMidia__c":""}


fetch("https://myurl.com",{
    method:"POST",
    mode:"no-cors",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body:JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Is it possible to use this mode in flutter?

I don't need the response, just send the data

thanks for any help